# Why not add ‘the’ before the last ‘steps’ word？

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I see a paragraph in a book:

> Editors of newspapers and magazines often go to extremes to provide their readers with unimportant facts and statistics. Last year a journalist had been instructed by a well-known magazine to write an article on the president's palace in a new African republic. When the article arrived, the editor read the first sentence and then refused to publish it. The article began: 'Hundreds of steps lead to the high wall which surrounds the president's palace.' The editor at once sent the journalist a fax instructing him to find out the exact number of **steps** and the height of the wall.

May you tell me why not add **the** before the last **steps**？

Comment: It's perfectly natural in English to use the "**zero article**" in such contexts, before a ***plural noun*** (but the *definite* article is required before the ***singular*** noun ***wall***). Also note that the article before ***height*** can be "deleted" because it's a "predictably repeated" element in the parallel construction *to find out the X and [to find out] [the] Y*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  If there is ‘walls’, should I add ‘the’ before ‘walls’？

Comment: He could have been told *to find out the exact number of steps and height of walls*. That's perfectly valid, and it's also possible to include ***the*** before ***height*** AND/OR ***walls*** there. I don't know how to explain ***why***, but whereas all those permutations are idiomatically at least "acceptable", I think almost no native speaker would ***ever*** endorse putting ***the*** in front of ***steps*** in your original example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not necessary. "the number of ____s" is the ordinary way to phrase counts of objects, not referring to "the steps" as in "the color of the steps", but to "how many steps there were".

Comment: If it is as you said, why did the author add ‘the’ before the last ‘wall’？  Just because ‘wall’ doesn’t contain ‘s’？

Comment: @Y.zeng No, if there were two walls it would be "the height of the walls" but "the number of walls".

Comment: Why should we add ‘the’ before ‘walls’ not before ‘steps’？

Comment: @Y.zeng in "the number of walls" there is no "the" before "walls", the same as for steps. They are not different in that case.

Comment: When we use the number of ‘___s’,  we needn’t add ‘the’ before ‘____s’.  Is this meaning？

Comment: @Y.zeng right, you don't need it, that's what I mean.

Comment: I never realised until you pointed it out here, but it does strike me as slightly "odd" that the article is fine in contexts like *the **colour** of the steps, the **size** of the steps*, but it would rarely if ever sit well in *the **number** of steps*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers it feels to me like a case where logically, in different contexts the forms with or without the "the" could fit better, but by custom we use the form without for both types of situations. "quantity" seems to work the same way, but not most nouns that could possibly refer to individual steps, even when used in context to refer to the sum total (length, weight, extent).

Comment: I should have waited for your response before swanning off to ELU and asking [“The number of Xs” - why no article?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/563200/the-number-of-xs-why-no-article) (at least you've provided a ***second*** attribute alongside "number" that has this syntactic constraint). Is it to do with whether or not the attribute (number, quantity, length,...) could / does attach to ***individual members of the set being referenced***, as opposed to "all of them **collectively**"? It's still "odd" to me.